# combinations python sum output

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list of numbers and I want to export a list showing the sum of every combination of these numbers.

so

```
x=[1,2,3]

output=[

1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6]
```

Is this possible?

```
x=[1137
,85
,15
,314
,4824
,21
,81
,63
,4514
,110
,51
,1
,1048
,13
]

def combs(s, lengths):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s,l) for l in lengths)

a=list((combs(x, list(range(len(x))))))
```

Comment: Sure it is. Please [edit] your question and include the code *you* have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: sure I've edited above, but I think I've over complicated it... i.e. don't think I need a function

Comment: apologies - updated

Comment: I just need the sum of them all

Comment: Looks like you are not summing anything.

Comment: yes that is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set comprehension:

```
from itertools import combinations
list({sum(c) for i in range(1, len(x) + 1) for c in combinations(x, i)})
```

This returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.combinations` for it:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> x+(list(map(sum,itertools.combinations(x,2)))[1:]+list(map(sum,itertools.combinations(x,3))))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```